# Get first number in a string after the first occurrence of identifier

Tags: php, regex, string

I'm working on a function that gets a string like this:

```
identifier 20 j. - cat: text text text aaaa dddd ..... cccc 60' - text, 2008
```

and extracts the number `20` so the first number in the string right after the first occurrence of `identifier` (including whitespace)

But if I had a string like this:

```
identifier j. - cat: text text text aaaa dddd ..... cccc 60' - text, 2008
```

the function should return NULL because there is no number right after the occurrence of `identifier` (including whitespace)

Could you please help me?
Thanks

Comment: Please include you attempt into your question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a regular expression for this:

```
$matches = array();
preg_match('/identifier\s*(\d+)/', $string, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

`\s*` is whitespace. `(\d+)` matches a number.

You can wrap it in a function:

```
function matchIdentifier($string) {
    $matches = array();
    if (!preg_match('/identifier\s*(\d+)/', $string, $matches)) {
        return null;
    }
    return $matches[1];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$string = "identifier 20 j. - cat: text text text aaaa dddd ..... cccc 60' - text, 2008";
$tokens = explode(' ', $string);
$token2 = $tokens[1];
if(is_numeric($token2))
{
    $value = (int) $token2;
}
else
{
    $value = NULL;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the match itslef without capturing subgroups using `\K` operator and `^` anchor to match the word only at the beginning of the string:

```
$re = "/^identifier \\K\\d+/"; 
$str = "identifier 20 j. - cat: text text text aaaa dddd ..... cccc 60' - text, 2008"; 
preg_match($re, $str, $matches);
echo $matches[0];
```

[Demo is here](https://regex101.com/r/vS3kV6/1).

Sample program is [available here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_php_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMV2NNTVZkVmJXSGM) (PHP v5.5.18).

Comment: NB: `\K` is [supported only for > 5.2.4](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php).

Comment: I am testing on TutorialsPoint, and they have PHP v5.5.18.

Comment: Yes, then it's fine. I just added it for reference.